# Combining extensions in ECMA6

Tags: javascript

I have a question about ECMA6 class extensions.  The "old" way allowed me to create a "class" (basically a function or object), and then "extend" it by adding to its prototype.  This makes it possible to have 3rd-party vendors write plugins for software and easily add them.  You would then simply have to instantiate the original "class", and it would have access to everything that had been added to its prototype.

In ECMA6 you can extend classes, but I fail to see how this can provide me with the same possibilities.  If vendor X extends my class Y, then now I would have to instantiate X instead of Y.  If another vendor adds its own extension Z, then now I have to know that they exist and then choose between X and Z.

I'm just starting to learn ECMA6 so I'm probably just missing something here.  How can I have an ECMA6 class, have different vendors extend it, and then on the fly get an instance that contains all functionalities (original class and all extensions)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can still add to it's prototype - classes are just wrappers around the prototype system. Also, what you were doing before was not extension (inheritance), it's monkey-patching and monkey-patching is generally still supported.

Comment: The same as before: `class Foo {}; Foo.prototype.fruit = function() {return 'mango'}`. Nothing has really changed.

Comment: Ok, I see now.  Quite easy, really.  Thanks :).  If you post an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing inheritance (which uses the `extends` keyword in ES6 `class` syntax) with augmenting ("extending" objects by mixing new methods into them).

> I fail to see how ES6 classes can provide me with the same possibilities

Nothing changed. ES6 classes are still just functions with a `.prototype` property, and you can amend their prototype objects like you always could.

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's not exactly pointless - just see how popular it is. Especially when subclassing, it's much safer as well (while staying simple to understand). And there are some aspects of `class`es that are not purely syntactic sugar, but they're not relevant for this question.